# Page is reloading and redirect to page with Json Response after submit button using AJAX Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using AJAX for insertion and fetching of data to database, upon submit button, page should not be reload or go to another page. In my case, it redirects to a page that display the JSON Response. Whenever I insert the fetch AJAX code, it happened. Should I put the fetch code to another script, I think they have conflict or I have declare it wrong please help.

This is my AJAX Code

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#customer_form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = this;
        $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
        });
        $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"/customer",
                data:new FormData(form),
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(response){
                    alert('hey');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

//THIS MAKES MY INSERTION REDIRECT TO THAT JSON RESPONSE

```
function fetchAllCustomer(){
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"/fetch-customer",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (response){
        // console.log(response.result);
        $.each(response.result, function(key, item)){
            $('tbody').append('<tr>\
                <td>'+item.id+'</td>\
                <td>'+item.first_name+'</td>\
                <td>'+item.last_name+'{{$customer ->last_name }}</td>\
                <td>'+item.mobile+'{{$customer ->mobile}}</td>\
                <td>'+item.email+'{{$customer ->email}}</td>\
                <td>'+item.gender+' </td>\
                <td>'+item.approval+'</td>\
                <td>'+item.status+'</td>\ 
                <td><button type="button" class="btn editbtn" style="background: none;\
                    color: inherit;\
                    border: none;\
                    padding: 0;\
                    font: inherit;\
                    cursor: pointer;\
                    outline: inherit;\
                    margin-top:-5px;\
                    "> <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>Update </button></td>\
                <td style="display:none;">'+item.gender+'</td>\
                <td style="display:none;">'+item.birthdate+'</td>\
                <td style="display:none;">'+item.address+'</td>\
                <td style="display:none;">'+item.lat+'</td>\
                <td style="display:none;">'+item.lng+'</td>\
                <td style="display:none;">'+item.approval+'</td>\
                <td style="display:none;">'+item.status+'</td>\
                <td style="display:none;">'+item.profile_image+'</td>\
                <td style="display:none;">'+item.is_verified+'</td>\
            </tr>');
        }
    }
});
}
</script>
```

This is my Controller Code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
        [
            'fname' => 'required',  
        ],
        [
            'fname.required' => 'must be first_name string', 
        ]
    );

    if(!$validator->passes()){
        return response()->json(['code'=>0,'error'=>$validator->errors()->toArray()]);
    }else{
        $path = 'files/';
        $file = $request->file('prof_image');
        $file_name = time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();

        //    $upload = $file->storeAs($path, $file_name);
        $upload = $file->storeAs($path, $file_name, 'public');

        if($upload){
            Customer::insert([
                'first_name'=>$request->fname,  
                'last_name' => $request->lname,
                'gender' => $request->gender,
                'birthdate' => $request->birthdate,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'mobile' => $request->mobile,
                'approval' => $request->approval,
                'status' => $request->status,
                'is_verified' => $request->is_verified,
                'address' => $request->address2,
                'lat' => $request->location_lat2,
                'lng' => $request->location_lang2,
                'profile_image'=> $file_name
            ]);
            return response()->json([
                'code'=>1,
                'msg'=>'New product has been saved successfully', 
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

And it redirect me to here
[image: Page]

Comment: It means that the jQuery code is not intercepting the submit event. It could be either because there's a JS error in the Console preventing any JS code being executed, or perhaps because the submit event handler is not bound to the form element correctly (perhaps because the selector is wrong or something). Can't tell the exact issue from the info provided so far, but those are the directions you need to look in.

Comment: hello sir @ADyson , I isolated the error and I updated my post, I think the function for fetching data that  I declare made it wrong, please help

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure how you've come to that conclusion? I don't see how `fetchAllCustomer()` is relevant? When/where do you call this function? How does it relate to submitting your form? It does not create any form code as far as I can see. And AJAX calls cannot make redirects. I've already told you the two possible reasons why your AJAX form submit is not working properly (so basically the page is just posting back to the controller action which returns JSON instead of running an AJAX request), you need to go and look at those.

Comment: Can we see your HTML form?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

don't use that in the controller:-

```
return response()->json([
     'code'=>1,
     'msg'=>'New product has been saved successfully', 
 ]);
```

use that in the controller:-

```
return redirect()->route('route.name', [$id]);
```